# Nested SQL query with NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I've been trying to figure out this question for a while but couldn't get it to work.

Relational schema:

Airport(name, country) -> name is the primary key

Flight(dep_airport, arr_airport) -> both attributes are foreign keys referencing Airport(name)

Question is:

> find Italian airports that do not have any international flights. The
>   SQL query has to be nested and use the NOT EXISTS operator.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT A.name
FROM airport AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT dep_airport.name AS dep_name, 
        dep_airport.country AS dep_country,
        arr_airport.name AS arr_name, 
        arr_airport.country AS arr_country
    FROM flight
    INNER JOIN airport dep_airport ON dep_airport.name = flight.dep_airport
    INNER JOIN airport arr_airport ON arr_airport.name = flight.arr_airport
    WHERE dep_airport.country <> arr_airport.country)
```

And also, how would one write this as a relational algebra query?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the schema set for these tables?  Why not have primary id's for each airport that links to other tables?

Comment: I often find these easier to write as a left anti-join, i.e. write a left join, then add `WHERE (right side) IS NULL`. But it looks like homework that specifies how you're meant to do it. Anyway, please show the schema.

Comment: Tip: in `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` there's no point returning any data in the `SELECT` clause; just `SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Your subquery appears to be uncorrelated, too. You don't reference `A` anywhere in the subquery. So it can't do what you think it does. You don't need to join on `airport` twice in the inner query, you can use an OR condition and test both directions in a single row, using airport `A` as the other airport, so you check for flights (A to other_airport) OR (from other_airport TO a) where the country of other_airport != the country of A. Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I'm still trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find these types of queries easier if you break them up into logical "chunks".

The first thing you need is to find all of the Italian airports

```
Select * from #Airports Where Country = 'Italy'
```

The second thing you need to do is find all of the flights departing from each of those airports where the arriving airport is not Italy.

```
Select * 
from #Flights 
Inner Join #Airports on #Flights.Arriving = #Airports.Name
And #Airports.Country <> 'Italy'
```

Now you need to do the exact opposite, find all flights arriving from each of those airports where the departing airport is not Italy.

```
Select * 
from #Flights 
Inner Join #Airports on #Flights.Departing= #Airports.Name
And #Airports.Country <> 'Italy'
```

At this point you have the 3 statements you need to meet the requirements, but you have to put it all together in a single statement.  You'll start with your first statement, because that's what you want to return to the user (the list of airports).  Then you'll add the next two statements as sub queries using a not exists for each.

```
Select  *
From    #Airports A
Where   Country = 'Italy'
And Not Exists  (
                    Select  1
                    From    #Flights F
                    Inner Join #Airports ASub on F.Arriving = ASub.Name
                    Where   A.Name = F.Departing
                    And     ASub.Country <> 'Italy'
                )
AND Not Exists  (
                    Select  1
                    From    #Flights F
                    Inner Join #Airports ASub on F.Departing = ASub.Name
                    Where   A.Name = F.Arriving
                    And     ASub.Country <> 'Italy'
                )
```

You should notice some minor tweaks to the two Not Exists statements.  Mainly, that I aliased the #Airports table and I added a condition to the where clause.  The alias for #Airports is due to the fact that I am selecting from #Airports in the "outer" statement as well as the "inner" (subquery) statement.  If I didn't do that, it would get the two mixed up and not know which reference to use.  The last thing that I did was I tied the two Not Exists back to the main query.  This is called correlating, and it's just a way to make sure that when you select from #Flights, that you are only pulling in Flights for the airports you are selecting (Italian airports)

One of the major benefits to Exists and Not Exists statements is that it typically allows you to remove the distinct keyword from your statements.  Distinct can cause extreme performance hits when returning large sets of data.  It can also make the query easier to read.

Comment: How to translate it into relational algebra?

Answer (score -1):

This may work... if not, just ignore.

```
CREATE TABLE Airports (
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Country VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Airports
VALUES  ('ABC', 'Italy'), ('DEF', 'Germany'), 
        ('GHI', 'Italy'), ('JKL', 'France'), 
        ('MNO', 'England'), ('PQR', 'Italy');

CREATE TABLE Flights (
  Departing VARCHAR(50),
  Arriving VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Flights
VALUES  ('ABC', 'PQR'), ('ABC', 'GHI'), 
        ('GHI', 'DEF'), ('JKL', 'GHI'), 
        ('MNO', 'PQR'), ('PQR', 'GHI'), ('ABC', 'PQR');


SELECT DISTINCT Departures.Name
FROM (Flights INNER JOIN Airports Departures ON Departures.Name = Flights.Departing) 
    INNER JOIN Airports Arrivals ON Arrivals.Name = Flights.Arriving
WHERE Departures.Country = Arrivals.Country
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Airports
                  WHERE Airports.Country = 'Italy')
```

Comment: I admit this does not use `EXISTS`.   Is there a specific requirement for using it.

Comment: Yeah it has to use NOT EXISTS

Comment: It uses EXISTS, it needs to have NOT EXISTS :)

Comment: otherwise I probably would've worked out the answer, it's just the annoying NOT EXISTS requirement...

Comment: @Bartek : it is not annoying; it is the most natural way to express your requirement : `SELECT * form airports a WHERE a.country = 'italy' AND NOT EXISTS (select * from Flights x join country y ON x.id2 =y.id where x.id = a.id and y.country <> 'Italy' )` OR ...